# Pushing content version (>50Mb) via REST API

Tags: rest-api, contentversion, node.js, binarydata

We are pushing / inserting files larger than 50Mb which is the reason we are using [multipart messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion) to push the data and this is being done via node.js

Now, the issue that I am facing is on the format of the data that goes into multipart information. I am not able to get the format right. In the example below I am pushing a local pdf file, but when it gets pushed into content version its a blank pdf.

```
  let fileBody = fs.readFileSync('localCopy.pdf'); //this is how I am reading the file body
  let body =
    '--boundary_string\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"\n' +
    'Content-Type: application/json\n' +
    '\n' +
    '{' +
    '    "FirstPublishLocationId" : "${FirstPublishLocationId}",\n' +
    '    "Title" : "${d.Title}",\n' +
    '    "PathOnClient" : "${d.PathOnClient}",\n' +
    '    "Origin" : "H"\n' +
    '}\n' +
    '\n' +
    '--boundary_string\n' +
    'Content-Type: ${mime.lookup(d.PathOnClient)}\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="${d.PathOnClient}"\n' +
    '\n' +
    '${fileBody}\n' +
    '\n' +
    '--boundary_string--';
  return body;
```

I am not sure how to generate the binary format which works fine. Request your help on the same.

Comment: you may want to look into using a NPM package like request(https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) that can handle all the multi-part minutiae as well putting together your HTTP headers instead of concatenating all of that in a single string. Here is a blog that shows how this could work

Comment: `request` is currently deprecated which is why I went with `axios`.. I think the formation of multipart body is fine, because the file is getting inserted in SF but it is coming as a blank pdf. I am not sure if the binary format that I am sending is correct or not.

Comment: Also, you mentioned a blog in your comment, can you provide the same. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.pjgalbraith.com/uploading-files-to-salesforce-using-jsforce/

Comment: Thanks much. That blog post was godsend! I used `form-data` with `axios`